# implementing search inside listview

Tags: android, listview

i want to implement a search inside my playlist. i was implementing getFilter in my custom array adapter, but it modifies the list, so if i was searching a song and its position was 9 and in my filter it was the only result, when i click on it, the song that will play is index 0 and not 9.

my code:

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {
            // When user changed the Text
            adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

listening to single listitem click

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting listitem index
            int songIndex = position;

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MusicPlayerActivity.class);
            // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
            in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
            setResult(SELECT_SONG, in);
            // Closing PlayListView
            finish();
        }
    });
```

my code inside play list adapter:

```
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        if (filter == null){
            filter  = new SongFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

private class SongFilter extends Filter
{
   @Override
   protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
           /* results.values = origonalList;
            results.count = origonalList.size();*/
            // We implement here the filter logic
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                synchronized (this)
                {
                    // No filter implemented we return all the list
                    results.values = MainAppConfig.playerService.getPlaylist();
                    results.count = MainAppConfig.playerService.getPlaylist().size();
                }
            }
            else {
                // We perform filtering operation
                ArrayList<Song> filter = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<Song> items = new ArrayList<>();

                synchronized (this)
                {
                    items.addAll(songList);
                }

                for (Song song : items ) {
                    if (song.getFileName().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                        filter.add(song);
                }

                results.values = filter;
                results.count = filter.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            filteredList = (ArrayList)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            Log.d("Filter", "Starting to publish the results with " + songList.size() + " items");
            for (int i = 0;  i < filteredList.size(); i++){
                add(filteredList.get(i));
            }
            Log.d("Filter", "Finished publishing results");
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list view doesn't know about the original position of the item in the adapter at this point, but you can find it yourself with something like:

```
Song song = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
MainAppConfig.playerService.getPlaylist().indexOf(song);
```